# Periodicworkrequest not working in newer version of android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am not able to call periodic work once in 16mins.It only calls when i run the app in the device.
Check the code below if i am doing any mistake.I am using One-plus 7t device.

Scope:I am trying to upload data present in Room Database to server once in 16mins.

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

    val repeatingRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<RefreshDataWorker>(16, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().//enqueue(repeatingRequest)
    enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            RefreshDataWorker.WORK_NAME,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            repeatingRequest)
```

And Dependency

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was not working is, Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes.

Better Suggestion to use the Alarm Manager. since i found PeriodicWorkRequest is not working in some of the devices and Respective android Versions.

for the reference you can visit Developer Website: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#min_periodic_interval_millis

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have used 16minutes interval but still it is not working. You have any code reference for Alarm Manager for MVVM Architecture?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it is not working in the One Plus Devices and Android 10 probably.

Comment: The periodic work shown above is set to 16 minutes. Alarm Manager is for different purpose.  I got the same issue on Android 12. Anyone who knows the solution for WorkManager's periodic work, please help.